# Guzzle and Symfony 3: Unresolved base url breaks composer install

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony, guzzle

In my Symfony 3 app, I'm using a service to get data from a rest api.

In this service, I'm injecting "session" and a string, representing the base url of my rest api.

```
public function __construct(Session $session, $magentoRestUrl)
{
    $this->session  = $session;
    $this->client   = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => $magentoRestUrl, // http://domain.com/rest/V1/
        'timeout'  => 2.0,
    ]);

    $this->cache = new ApcuAdapter();

    $this->groupedIngredients = [];
}
```

Until now, everything worked as expected on my local machine. But now, during the deployment process with an `$magentoRestUrl` that does not yet exist, I'm getting this error when running `composer install --no-dev`:

```
...
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException]                                                                               
cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: domain.com (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)  

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**My question is**: Why does `composer install` trigger guzzle to resolve the `$magentoRestUrl`? Is it, because it's in the constructor of the service class?

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "alex/symfony",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
    "leafo/scssphp": "^0.6.3",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony framework uses `post-install-cmd` and `post-update-cmd` scripts from your `composer.json` that are called automatically by Composer to initialize caches, create its `bootstrap.php.cache` and so on.

I think one of these internally has to work with the dependency injector and one of the dependencies need to resolve also your service (this depends on your service configuration) that throws this error.

Comment: Seems to be impossible to make this work, because the base_url set in GuzzleClient initialization in service constructor will never be resolvable during deployment process. Is there anything wrong in how I created the service?

Comment: Maybe you could make the dependency optional https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/optional_dependencies.html write an expression in DI config with some logic that checks current environemnt https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html